# Android TextView showing color hex as default

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

In Android Studio the preview view is showing the color hex code in the textview as if I have set it as the text attribute. [Here is an image showing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USsxA.png)

It also is appearing like this when I install it to my phone.
I'm not sure what I've done to make this happen. I recently updated Android studio and the build tools etc.

I can't find anything about this online. Anyone else having this problem or know what is happening?

Here is the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" in r/" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <!-- todo theme color -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="?attr/text_colour_primary"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nsfwTag"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numComments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_micro" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/domain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_micro" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hoursAgoPosted"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_micro" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this the exactly same XML you have posted. Text won't be appear until you set text attribute or programatically.

Comment: That's what I'm saying the problem is. Its the exact same xml and the hexcode is showing as though I have added it using the text attribute. Never had this issue before. It has only happened recently

Comment: and what if you explicitly set text to ""(empty) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In the folder res/values add an xml file called "colors.xml"

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
        <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    </resources>
```

2. Set the color attribute like this:

```html
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Let me know if this solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

### - Instead of writing this line

android:textColor="?attr/text_colour_primary"

---

### - You can write code like this

android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"

Comment: I'm using attributes so I can implement a theme changer easily later. I've never had a problem using this method before. It is something that has happened recently so I must have dont something to cause it

Answer (score 0):

It appears that somewhere along the line in my development I added this line to my theme in styles.xml:

```
 <item name="android:text">@color/text_black_secondary</item>
```

It added the colour code to the text of every TextView.